# graphic card driver fails after installing cuda

Tags: cuda

I just installed the CUDA package , now my HDMI port does not give out any signal, the monitor is always black.

I checked device manager , there seem to be some issue with the Graphic card driver. but when I try to update it , it says the best graphic card is already installed.[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue with the CUDA 10.2 windows installer that is *currently* available.  It should be rectified soon.

See [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1067201/cuda-setup-and-installation/known-issue-with-cuda-10-2-windows-10-installer/).

> We are aware of a signing issue with the NVIDIA drivers bundled with the Windows 10 installer for CUDA 10.2 (10.2.89 with 441.22 driver). Users may see a Code 52 error from Windows warning that the signatures cannot be verified. In the meantime, users are advised to install the latest NVIDIA driver from the driver downloads site (https://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us) and then uncheck the driver install option during the installation of CUDA 10.2.
>
> We are working on a fix and we will be reposting the CUDA 10.2 installer packages as soon as possible. We apologize for any inconvenience.

**UPDATE:** this should now be fixed in the installers currently provided at http://www.nvidia.com/getcuda